# How to turn off css:hover for kendo grid (.k-grid tr:hover) without modifying the kendo css?

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, hover, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid on Cordova app. Here on the grid, the scrolling is jagged due to the css rule 'k-grid tr:hover' in kendo css. If I disable this rule from developer tools, scrolling is smooth. Is there any way to disable this hover rule?

I don't want to override hover behaviour. I want to disable it.

Edit: The problem is due to hover the scrolling is not smooth on the grid. The scroll starts after touchend of the swipe but instead it should move with touchmove. This causes the scrolling to be jagged. Removing the hover rule solves this and makes scroll smooth.

Do ask for further clarification if necessary.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to modify the kendo css?

Comment: My lead wont allow me to.. *-_- ,else I can just remove that rule. But it is supposed to be bad practice to modify the external api.

Comment: I can understand the lead's point of view.  However, we used a customized kendo CSS that we built using the online tool that Telerik provided for that purpose, from the start so that we would be consistent with internal design standards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pointer-events: none property on the DOM element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

```
.k-grid tr {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

With this property, the hover event on that element will be completely ignored.

Comment: I tried this but I have a checkbox and a clickable item in table row. These element click events are also not firing.

Comment: This did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

I've "solved" it by disabling the hover and then replicating the tr even background color:

```
.k-grid tr:hover {
    background: none;
}

.k-grid tr.k-alt:hover {
    background: none;
}

.k-grid tr.k-alt:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

of course you can play with the colors

Comment: This is the correct way. You do not loose any hover DOM event. Just keep in mind that your `.k-alt` row color might not be `#f5f5f5` depending on the theme.

Answer (score 0):

I took hint from Gabriel's answer but I applied pointer events none to the td elements inside .k-grid tr. But this is just a temporary fix as this removes the possibility of adding pointer events to those td elements. I am still looking for a better alternative.